# Determine the main memory size using cache line and cache size

Tags: memory-management, caching

Assume a computer architecture with 32 bit address.The system has been designed with 1MB cache which comes with 64KB cache line(cache block size).

1.What is the maximum main memory capacity this system can have?

Since computer architecture is 32 bit does it mean word size is 4 bytes?am i correct?

Words in one cahce line= 64KB/4Bytes= 2**18 words

Total cache blocks= 1MB/64KB=8 cache blocks

Am i going the right direction?I dont know what to do after this.Plz point me t the right direction.Thank you

Comment: With 32 address bits you can address $2^{32}$ different locations.

Comment: Thank you.I think you are correct.Also one problem can we assume word size is 4 bytes because architecture is 32 bit?

Comment: This would be the first guess, though the word size could also be smaller or larger.